# jQuery UI, resize the last div responsively

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to make the last div always fill the end by pulling it to the left, decreasing its size by pushing it to the right and when changing the size of the first div does not affect the last div only the first and second div?
In the code below, for exceeding the size of the `caixa`, the div goes to the bottom.

**[codepen.io e.g.](http://codepen.io/pen/)**

```js
$(".caixa").resizable({
   handles: "s", 
   minHeight: 50,
   maxHeight: 300
});
$(".ta").resizable({
   handles: "e",
});
```

```css
.caixa {
  background-color: #444;
 /* margin: 100px auto; */
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom:2px;
}
.ta {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  padding-right:2px;
}
.ta1 {
  background-color: #000;
}
.ta2 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.ta3 {
  background-color: #888;
}
textarea {
  resize:none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="caixa">
   <div class="ta ta1"><textarea></textarea></div>
   <div class="ta ta2"><textarea></textarea></div>
   <div class="ta ta3"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
```